# Identifying location and cause of death of person who died in 1992?

Tags: australia, death-records, queensland

I have visited the grave site, obtained the headstone details but unable to progress from there.

- Buried in Bundaberg Queensland
- Death location unknown
- Whereabouts between 1985 and 1992 unknown
- Parents deceased
- Spouse died 3 years later (details unknown)
- No trace in local newspaper

---

Following on from the suggestions, I have approached the Bundaberg Cemetery with no further information available.

I enquired at the 2 stonemasons. One has no record on their computer system for the name. The other does not have computerised records from that period and was not willing to look through archived files.

I followed up with a previous employment and learnt that the individual and spouse had not lived together from the time he went missing. They thought she had not heard from him. The staff at the previous employment were unaware of his location, do not know where he died or how. They did say it was not in Bundaberg and that the police had been involved in the investigation.

I have approached QLD police to see if they have further details and if available, I will request under FOI.

In the meantime I wait for the release of the death details in 2022.

Comment: Is the spouse buried in the same cemetery? Could you focus on the spouse and learn where they were between 1985 and the year they died? Have you checked local phone directories?

Comment: The spouse is buried in the same cemetery. She has no living relatives and I have no details of any friends. They were separated during most of the period his whereabouts were not known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not give an age so I am assuming an adult. It appears you may have details of 1985 and before. Are any of these able to give an avenue to investigate eg employment location, previous places of residence, schools. You may be able to obtain information from friends or work colleagues.

Answer (score 11):

Since you have a full name and date of death in Queensland you can obtain information on the location and cause of death from the Death Certificate filed with the Registrar.

Details are in the [Certificate Access Policy](http://www.justice.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/58341/Certificate-Access-Policy.pdf).

In short, you need to

- find a direct descendant (eligible on Family grounds now), or
- wait for another 10 years (when it becomes an historical record).

Otherwise, you need to look for other forms of evidence. Does anything on the headstone help you in identifying the undertaker?

There appear to be two monumental masons working in the area (Zeigler and Allen). You can obtain their contact details through the [Bundaberg Regional Council website](http://bundaberg.qld.gov.au/services/cemeteries).

Comment: As well as identifying the undertaker, is the burial plot registered in a particular person's name?

Answer (score 1):

These or similar question may help you find more information.*

- Does the cemetery maintain records that you (or, as above, someone who qualifies as a family member) are able to access? Cemeteries in some locations maintain files or records of burials and burial arrangements.
- Is there a deed or other public record of the plot owner?
- Are you able to learn the name of the monument company? Does that company maintain a file or records about the transaction that might report where the person died.
- Are you able to learn from the cemetery or local authorities if a burial permit was required in 1992? Is the burial permit a public record that you are able to access?
- What were the special local or cemetery requirements in 1992 for the burial of a body when the death had occurred elsewhere? Was any special public record created for this?

*Understanding local privacy interests may help in communication with officials. For example, family members names might be considered private, but where the person died or the date of that burial might not be.